# Cache won't work in Appcelerator

Tags: caching, appcelerator

Titanium SDK version: 1.6.
iPhone SDK version: 4.2

I am trying out the cache snippet found on the Appcelerator forum but I get an error: [ERROR] Script Error = Can't find variable: utils at cache.js (line 9).

I put this one (http://pastie.org/1541768) in a file called cache.js and implemented the code from this one (http://pastie.org/pastes/1541787) in the calling script, but I get the error.

What is wrong? I copied the code exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problems is whilst the first pastie defines `utils.httpcache`. The variable `utils` is not defined outside of this function closure (because it is not defined anywhere in global namespace). As below shows.

```
(function() {
  utils.httpcache = {

  };
})();
```

**To make it all work** in this instance add the following code to the top of your cache.js file.

```
var utils = {};
```

This declares the `utils` variable in global namespace. Then when the function closure is executed below it will add `utils.httpcache` to the `utils` object.

The problem is actually not specific to Appcelerator and is just a simple JavaScript bug. Checkout [Douglas Crockfords book, JavaScript the Good Parts](http://www.amazon.co.uk/JavaScript-Good-Parts-Douglas-Crockford/dp/0596517742). Reading it will literally make you a more awesome JavaScript developer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `utils.httpcache.getFromCache(url)` until you add this to your code:

```
var utils = {};
```

That's because how the author created his function, it's called JavaScript module pattern and it's generally used to structure the code.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to lose this value "value.httpCacheExpire = expireTime;" when the code does the "Titanium.App.Properties.setString(key,JSON.stringify(value));" so when I get it back using the getString method, there's no longer the "value.httpCacheExpire.

Anyone else have this issue? Am I missing something to get this working?